# How can I get my NodeJS app to start in Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have a NodeJS (version 8) app I am trying to get to run in Docker locally.

When using 
    `docker-compose up`
after the build, i get this error:

```
app_1       | /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: 1: /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: �����H: not found
app_1       | /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: 2: /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: ���H__PAGEZERO__TEXT: not found
app_1       | /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: 3: /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: Y.__dof_node__TEXT�c.�c.__unwind_info__TEXT�l.�L�l.__eh_frame__TEXTP�/dP�__DATA: not found
app_1       | /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: 4: /app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
app_1       | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app_1       | npm ERR! errno 2
app_1       | npm ERR! app-backend@ start:production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./server.js`
app_1       | npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Trying to run the container directly with docker `run --rm -it  my_app sh` and trying `cd backend && npm run start:production`
i get the same error. The debug log says:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start:production' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v8.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart:production',
4 verbose run-script   'start:production',
4 verbose run-script   'poststart:production' ]
5 info lifecycle app-backend@~prestart:production: app-backend@
6 info lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: app-backend@
7 verbose lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/app/backend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: CWD: /app/backend
10 silly lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: Args: [ '-c', 'cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./server.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle app-backend@~start:production: Failed to exec start:production script
13 verbose stack Error: app-backend@ start:production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./server.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid app-backend@
15 verbose cwd /app/backend
16 verbose Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start:production"
18 verbose node v8.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error app-backend@ start:production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon ./server.js`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the app-backend@ start:production script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  Including both your `Dockerfile` and your `docker-compose.yml` or `docker run` command would be helpful.  (In particular, something like this could happen if you're bind-mounting your `node_modules` directory into the container; removing Compose `volumes:` or a `docker run -v` option would help with this.)

Comment: Currently I am using this `docker run --rm -ti my_app sh`, when trying to run any npm script inside it, I see the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Put your NODE_ENV at docker compose like this:

```
  server:
    image: your_image
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

Then you can simplify your CMD to just CMD ["nodemon", "./server.js"]

Comment: This did not work for me. In my container, I tried running nodemon by itself like this: `npm run env -- nodemon` but get the same error as above

Comment: What if you exec into docker container and try to start your app?

```docker exec -it your_image bash```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here in case anyone sees a similar error:
In my package.json, I had a dependency on node:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "node": "^8.10.0",
    ...
  }
```

After removing this line, the docker container starts up correctly.